# Is there a research paper which analyzes the economic crisis 2008 by quantifiable critera?

Tags: research, economic-crisis

I need to find a paper which analyzes the economic crisis in 2008 (by quantifiable critera). My task is to apply such criteria to the current situation. I have to use a research paper as a basis for my work, but sadly I couldn't find something which highlights key factors to look for to detect a economic crisis. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at Ohanian (2010): The Economic Crisis from a Neoclassical Perspective at https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.24.4.45
It's an accessible application of business cycle accounting.

Comment: Thank you jpfeifer, your answer was extremely helpful for my task. But I need to ask you one question. Do you know how the labor, capital and productivity deviation is calculated (see page 53)? Which data do I need to calculate those for the current economic situation (2018 - 2020+)?

Comment: It depends on the exact implementation. Usually you need information on GDP, hours worked, the capital or investment, and consumption. Essentially the variables in Table 1.